# ASP.NET MVC Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

I am starting with orchard cms, my basic requirement is not to create a blog, but a cms for a small company. I have a requirement where I need to display a list of product which will change daily, Is there a option where I can create a custom table for product and insert form in orchard and allow production admin to update list.

Please help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To display a list of items you can use the Projections module. This a decent introduction to what the Projections module does: http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/projector-module-in-orchard-cms . This gives much more detail about how to actually use it: http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5 I would strongly recommend following that entire line of tutorials by Sipke Schoorstra. It will give you a great understanding of Orchard.

To change what items are displayed you could simply publish and unpublish items. But this may not be suitable, so you could try using the Taxonomies module, create a taxonomy and attach this to your content type. Then only display items in your projection if they have the taxonomy you created selected.

Something along those lines should work for you :)